# Printing only records in page instead of all the records in a table

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a table of 300 records and I have developed a `adf` page where 300 records are shown in page. Each page consist of only 25 records.

My requirement is to print only record which is available in page, instead of all the records in table.

Answer (score 0):

The af:exportCollectionActionListener only allow to either download all or selected lines. You can try having a button selecting allRowInRange (the 25 displayed) and then triggering the af:exportCollectionActionListener.

Comment: Can you explain in  detail brother? i am having panel group layout and having layout as ''page" so it displays total records in 10 page and i want to print only the corresponding records from current page brother ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jasper report to export it as PDF or excel from ADF app, you can use query parameter in report level to print data that are being displayed on page